# Extracting files using batch file in Control M

Tags: batch-file, control-m

I have a `batch file` which has command:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x Y:\lit\tail\ger\ger\FTP\SMS\2022-05-31\
```

It runs successfully when runned manually by doubling clicking the `unzip.bat` file.So, I implement this batch file to be run from Control-M:

[image]

But when the job runs from Control M it says `"The system cannot find the path specified."`. My files have no extensions in them.
[image]

How can I make control M extract the files?

Comment: We need more information. Are you tring to 'run as administrator' your batch file? Is the drive letter `Y:` actually mapped as such for the user your are running this under, and at the time you are attempting to do so? Are you running this as a Scheduled Task? In order for us to help you diagnose the issue, and provide possible solutions, you need to submit sufficient information for us to reproduce the issue you are reporting.

Comment: This is via Control-M. It is easy to create a Command type job, adjust as required;


`@echo off && net use * /DELETE /YES & net use X: "\\MY\NETWORK\FOLDER\HERE" && net use Z: "\\ANOTHER\NETWORK\FOLDER\HERE" my_password /USER:mydomain\myuser && @echo on && cd X: && zip Z:\FILETOBEZIPPED.zip X:*file.xml -rt OUTPUT_DATESTAMP & net use X: /DELETE /YES & net use Z: /DELETE /YES & net use`


here the echo off/on is just to hide your details from prying eyes. You need to have the zip software running on the local box too. The rest is just setting up the network mappings.

Comment: Are you running on the right agent? The error is from 7zip or from Control-M? I mean, in the output do you have "Scanning the drive for archives:"?